# unable to draw mkpolyline

Tags: ios, xcode, gps, mkmapview

I have used `MKMapView` to show map and current user location which is working correctly.
Now I want to draw a polyline as user moves but it is not working I tried follwing code:

```objc
for(int i = 0; i < [longarray count]; i++)
{
    NSNumber *latt=[latarray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSNumber *lonn=[longarray objectAtIndex:i];
    sklat =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",latt]doubleValue];
    sklongi =[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",lonn]doubleValue];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate1 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(sklat,sklongi);
    // break the string down even further to latitude and longitude fields.
    MKMapPoint point = MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate1);
    // if it is the first point, just use them, since we have nothing to compare to yet.
    pointsArray[i] = point;
}
self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithPoints:pointsArray count:[latarray count]];
free(pointsArray);
[mapview addOverlay:self.routeLine];
```

then i usedd overlay function as

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKOverlayView* overlayView = nil;
    if(overlay == self.routeLine)
    {
        routeLineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:self.routeLine] ;
        routeLineView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:5.100 blue:0.100  alpha:1];
        routeLineView.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.000 green:5.100 blue:0.100 alpha:1];
        routeLineView.lineWidth = 4;
        overlayView = routeLineView;
    }
    return overlayView;
}
```

Comment: what is not working? is the delegate callback being called?

Comment: please elaborate...i have called delegate for location manager and map...is there something else which i am missing?
and polyline is not drawing on map.

Comment: Have you checked that the viewForOverlay function is actually being called? Set a break point or add a log statement.   As a side note you can skip the NSString part of that line and get the doubleValue of the NSNumber `sklat =[latt doubleValue];`

Comment: yes i  have checked viewForOverlay function is never called...so wat could i do please suggest solution ...

Comment: did you assign the delegate to the mapview?